# What is the result of readPNG function?

Tags: r, png

I don't think I understand the function `readPNG`. In help we can find this piece of code

```
img <- readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png"))
```

`img` is the numieric vector num[1:76 1:100 1:4] (but it is dispalyed in a form of four matrices)

When I read some another PNG file (25 x 25, logical [only black or white pixels]) I get vector num[1:25 1:25 1:3]. It seems like these three logical matrices are the same. Could you please explain me what exactly is the result of readPNG function? Why once it is dispalyed as 4 matrices, once as three?

Comment: You failed to mention that the function is from the package **png**. Have you read the Value section of the documentation at `?readPNG`? Can you say what specifically is confusing about that explanation?

Comment: Isn't because the files decompress into RGB (3 channels)?

Answer (score 1):

While I'll concede many of the R manual pages are obtuse, this one is pretty good.

```
Value

If native is FALSE then an array of the dimensions height x width x
channels. If there is only one channel the result is a matrix. The
values are reals between 0 and 1. If native is TRUE then an object of
the class nativeRaster is returned instead. The latter cannot be
easily computed on but is the most efficient way to draw using
rasterImage.

Most common files decompress into RGB (3 channels), RGBA (4 channels),
Grayscale (1 channel) or GA (2 channels). Note that G and GA images
cannot be directly used in rasterImage unless native is set to TRUE
because rasterImage requires RGB or RGBA format (nativeRaster is
always 8-bit RGBA).

As of png 0.1-2 files with 16-bit channels are converted in full
resolution to the array format, but the nativeRaster format only
supports 8-bit and therefore a truncation is performed (eight least
significant bits are dropped) with a warning if native is TRUE.
```

Comment: Thank you but I still have a question. My image is in grauscale (actualy it has only two colors, black or white) so why R sees it as image with 3 chanells instead of 1? I get matrices with value 0-1 (they are exactly the same). Is there any way to change it?